# Input styling is not uniform

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, spinner

Check out how ugly this is:

[image: Imgur]

Here is my XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Style"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Position" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/array_positions"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Icon Color" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="red"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How do I make it so the spinner and edittext always look the same? I've even tried adding `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"` to the spinner, and while it add the bottom line, the padding and font size is still different.